# Transforming an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ to $g(X)$ that is reducible (over $\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a way to construct a linear transformation $x = \alpha X + \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ that yields the polynomial $g(X)$ that is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$?

If a linear transformation is not possible, is there a simple rational function transformation of the form

$$x = {k(X) \over m(X)}$$

that yields $g(X)$ that is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If we have, say, $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, how would that work with $\alpha = 2, \beta = 0$? It seems to me we would have $g(X) = \frac14X^2 + 1$.

Comment: @Arthur: I think I made a mistake when speficying the transformation. I have expanded the question to also include simple rational function transformations.